# Sharpening before color and size adjustments?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Should I make color and image size adjustments before sharpening or after?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sharpening always comes after everything. it's the last touch of the picture. unless you use a specific photo retouching technique. but for the general part. it comes last

Answer (score 0):

Post. I would always keep a full size, original, hi-resolution version of the file and then sharpen as part of your final pre-process before delivery,for example, for screen / web which may look fluffy after you have sized it down significantly.

Sharpening will deteriorate the image all be it less noticeably at high resolution. However, if you were to print that file out for a 25 foot billboard you would certainly see it.

In terms of colour, if you are not aware, make these changes in RGB which has a wide gamut (range effectively), then convert to CMYK if you need a print image - again pre-process and keep the RGB original. Reason is CMYK has a smaller gamut and so will lose a good deal of colour information in the file.

Hope this helps.

If you think about it, smaller = less pixels to work with in the first place + greater change per pixel when you make any adjustment.